# Help Building a Partitioning of a Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Suppose I have an undirected graph, $G$, with vertices $V_1 \ldots V_n$ and edges $E_1 \ldots E_n$.  Each vertex $V_i$ has a associated positive ($>0$) weight $W_i$.  I would like to partition $G$ into partitions $P_1 \ldots P_p$ where a number of conditions are met, such as:

1. Each vertex is in exactly one partition.
2. All of the vertices in a single partition are connected.
3. (This is the kicker.) The sum of the vertex weights for each partition are "approximately equal".

If you happen to have an answer, I'll gladly accept it; but what I'm more realistically looking for is a name for this type of problem so that I can go off and research it possible solutions.

Comment: So the number of vertices and edges are equal? Also is $p$ fixed? (Otherwise you can just pick $p=1$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find lots of information by searching for *political districting problem*.  The idea is that each node corresponds to an indivisible geographic region (usually, census tract), and an edge joining two nodes indicates that the regions share a geographic border.  The node weight is the population of the region, and $p$ is the number of districts to be formed.  Your third condition on approximately equal populations relates to the "[one man, one vote"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_man,_one_vote) principle.

In the political districting literature, there is also a compactness metric to avoid *gerrymandering*, but you can omit that.  See [Using the OPTMODEL Procedure in SAS/OR® to Solve Complex Problems](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/SAS1502-2015.pdf) and [Imposing contiguity constraints in political districting models](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2020/01/7582.pdf).